# What does "dominant query" mean when related to database tables?

Tags: sql, database, azure

When reading about how to get the most out of Azure Tables, they mention "Avoid scans for dominant queries" as part of their conclusion.

What does it mean by "dominant queries"?

I've seen it mentioned in a few other questions but I do not have enough reputation to comment on other's answers yet so am asking as new question. Feel free to give feedback on that rather than downvoting this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a concept specific to database systems rather than a programming problem. One would instead consider visiting [Database Administrators SE](//dba.stackexchange.com) (but check the site's [guidelines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first).

Comment: Shall I change the question instead? I had only started in the industry back then and was working on an API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Select the dominant queries and updates based on such criteria as high frequency of execution, high volume of data accessed, response time contraints, or explicit high priority. Remember this rule of thumb: **Any process whose frequency of execution or data volume accessed is 10 times that of another process is considered to be dominant**."

Quote from book: *Database Design: Know It All*

Authors: *Toby J. Teorey, Stephen Buxton, Lowell Fryman, Ralf Hartmut Güting, Terry Halpin, Jan L. Harrington, W.H. Inmon, Sam S. Lightstone, Jim Melton, Tony Morgan, Thomas P. Nadeau, Bonnie O'Neil, Elizabeth O'Neil, Patrick O'Neil, Markus Schneider, Graeme Simsion, Graham Witt*

Publisher: *Morgan Kaufmann, 23/10/2008*

Answer (score 0):

"dominant queries" - most frequently run queries